# Facebook feed dialog deprecating custom fields

Tags: ajax, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Feed Dialog 2.9 has deprecated the custom fields (name, caption, picture, description) - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog.

I'm working on an AJAX site where all content and metadata is loaded dynamically. If I just use the link property, the metadata isn't set on initial retrieval of the page so the post doesn't contain the right content.

How can I share an AJAX page on Facebook without having to go down the route of prerendering static pages server side? Thanks

Comment: _“How can I share an AJAX page on Facebook without having to go down the route of prerendering static pages server side?”_ - you can’t any more.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :( Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score -1):

If you can program your page to populate the appropriate metatags on the page load based off of a variable http:/yoursite.com/yourpage.php?thisversion=1 then when you want to share version 1 of the page, you just share the URL with the appropriate variable to populate it.  You can still remain on your current version of the page but when you share the URL that would prompt that specific version, facebook makes a call to that respective URL and pulls the appropriate metatags that would be populated by your variable without having to reload the page your are currently displaying.  Sorry I don't have time at the moment but will try and comeback and add some sample code for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar but without versions in the query string. I'm using .Net so I've written an IIS URL rewrite which redirects if the user agent = 'facebookexternalhit'. So in that case it serves up a basic HTML response with the relevant metatags. Bit of a pain, but I think I'm going to need to do something similar for SEO anyway so it was probably a step in a direction I need to go regardless.